# Combining tiles with Slick2D

Tags: java, 2d, slick2d

I am working on a simple 2D game with use of Slick2D

But I have one problem that shouldn't be one, but I can't find
the correct answer anywhere.

My question is:
How can I combine tiles of a spritesheet?
One tile is 32 x 32 pixels. I have a sprite for the player that uses 3 tiles in height and
one in width. Now I want to display the whole player and I am wondering how I can say
that the image of the player goes from tile (3,0) to (3,3) on the sheet.

How I define the spritesheet:

```
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
      spritesheet = new SpriteSheet("res/sprite_sheet.png", 32, 32);

  }
```

How I render it:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

      map.render(200, 100);
      g.drawString("Collision: "+collides, 10, 60);
      g.draw(pointer);

      spritesheet.startUse();
      playerImage = //I need to combine them here I guess?
      spritesheet.endUse();
      playerImage.draw();

  }
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around a lot I found out the solution for this.

You can extend yourImageHere.draw() to yourImageHere.draw(x, y, width, height)
x and y is the coordinate where your sprite on the image (spritesheet) starts, in pixels
width and height defines the size of the image frome there.